# MySQL CDRs in Asterisk 11?

Tags: mysql, asterisk

It appears that since Asterisk 1.8 MySQL CDR storage is built-in (cdr_mysql.so is deprecated as is the Asterisk Add-ons).  I have a cdr_mysql.conf configured (similar settings as in res_config_mysql.conf which works) and I have mySQL running and the cdr table created (and yes Asterisk can write to the tables).  BUT, I get no CDRs in that table (I do get the Master.csv CDRs).  What am I missing?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**No ODBC!** Just **enable** all Mysql (even if it depreceted) in **make menuselect** and run:

```
make clean & make & make install
```

**make clean - is necessary!** 
In **modules.conf** write next:

```
load => app_db.so
load => app_cdr.so
load => app_mysql.so
load => cdr_csv.so
load => cdr_mysql.so
load => func_cdr.so
load => func_db.so
```

In **cdr.conf**

```
[general]
enable=yes
```

In **cdr_mysql.conf** - all for connect to MySQL.

after all this go to CLI and type **cdr show status** and looking for mysql! )) Try to use this command before)

```
CLI> cdr show status
Call Detail Record (CDR) settings
----------------------------------
  Logging:                    Enabled
  Mode:                       Simple
  Log unanswered calls:       Yes
  Log congestion:             No

* Registered Backends
  -------------------
    mysql
    csv
```

Answer (score 0):

In asterisk 11 cdr_mysql still selactable via

```
make menuconfig
```

It is depricated. Since cdr_odbc work same, i not see any issue in that.

You also need have cdr.conf file with

```
[general]

; Define whether or not to use CDR logging.  Setting this to "no" will override
; any loading of backend CDR modules.  Default is "yes".
enable=yes
```

And cdr_custom.conf with something like this

```
[mappings]
Master.csv => ${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(clid)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(src)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(dst)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(dcontext)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(channel)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(dstchannel)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(lastapp)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(lastdata)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(start)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(answer)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(end)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(duration)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(billsec)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(disposition)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(amaflags)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(accountcode)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(uniqueid)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(userfield)})},${CDR(sequence)}
```

Comment: Deprecated suggests that at some point with little or no warning the capability will disappear.  That would be bad!  My question though is what the truth is:  Does Asterisk 11 do MySQL directly or only the ODBC?